# How to write test case for android app

Tags: android, unit-testing, variables

I am trying to write an android test case -

how do I test if a variable is null

i have this code

```
String request = getRequestString();
LinkedHashMap<String, String> cookie = sendPostRequest(MainActivity.this, url, request);
```

how do i test the contents of request and the contents of cookie ?

Comment: `if(cookie != null)`??

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of unit tests is not to check the inner workings of a function but to test its output and behaviour as a whole. Therefore you shouldn't try to test inner variables.

Comment: how does it know what "cookie" is, if it is not a class variable ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is the code posted above from your unit test method?

Comment: no - it is from the actual app

and these variables are local method variables

Comment: i have a unit test- the question was  how inside the unit test do i reach those variables, if they are not class variables,but local inside a function???